# Adding immutable Vectors

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to work more with scalas immutable collection since this is easy to parallelize, but i struggle with some newbie problems. I am looking for a way to create (efficiently) a new Vector from an operation. To be precise I want something like

```
val v : Vector[Double] = RandomVector(10000)
val w : Vector[Double] = RandomVector(10000)
val r = v + w
```

I tested the following:

```
// 1)
val r : Vector[Double] = (v.zip(w)).map{ t:(Double,Double) => t._1 + t._2 }

// 2)
val vb = new VectorBuilder[Double]()    
var i=0
while(i<v.length){
  vb += v(i) + w(i)
  i = i + 1
}
val r = vb.result
```

}

Both take really long compared to the work with Array:

```
[Vector Zip/Map   ] Elapsed time 0.409 msecs
[Vector While Loop] Elapsed time 0.374 msecs
[Array While Loop ] Elapsed time 0.056 msecs
// with warm-up (10000) and avg. over 10000 runs
```

Is there a better way to do it? I think the work with zip/map/reduce has the advantage that it can run in parallel as soon as the collections have support for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`Vector` is not specialized for `Double`, so you're going to pay a sizable performance penalty for using it.  If you are doing a simple operation, you're probably better off using an array on a single core than a `Vector` or other generic collection on the entire machine (unless you have 12+ cores).  If you still need parallelization, there are other mechanisms you can use, such as using `scala.actors.Futures.future` to create instances that each do the work on part of the range:

```
val a = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
(0 to 4).map(_ * (a.length/4)).sliding(2).map(i => scala.actors.Futures.future {
  var s = 0
  var j = i(0)
  while (j < i(1)) {
    s += a(j)
    j += 1
  }
  s
}).map(_()).sum  // _() applies the future--blocks until it's done
```

Of course, you'd need to use this on a much longer array (and on a machine with four cores) for the parallelization to improve things.

Comment: To add to this: the "`Vector` is not specialized for `Double`" means that to put the numbers in a `Vector`, they will be boxed into `Double` wrapper objects. All the boxing and unboxing each time you access an element of the `Vector` will cost a lot of performance.

Comment: How Hard Would It Be for someone to ship a collection of specialized collections to go along with the main Scala distribution?  Would it work?  Would it be relatively idiomatic?

Comment: @Alex Cruise - It is tricky.  Collections exist in an elaborate hierarchy, and pretty much everything in that hierarchy needs to be specialized and then tested.  And then there's a lot of higher-order type magic, and it's not entirely clear (to me, anyway) how to meld that ideally with specialization.

Comment: Thanks! I supposed `Vector` is the immutable version of `Array`. So there is no immutable Array in Scala?


@Rex: Does your solution have an advantage over `ParArray`?

Comment: @Markus - `ParArray` is not specialized.  `Vector` acts pretty much like an immutable `Array`, but it is also not specialized.  The reason `Array` is an exception is that it is a plain old Java array (which has different versions for each primitive type, plus Object).

Answer (score 4):

You should use lazily built collections when you use more than one higher-order methods:

```
v1.view zip v2 map { case (a,b) => a+b }
```

If you don't use a view or an iterator each method will create a new immutable collection even when they are not needed.

Probably immutable code won't be as fast as mutable but the lazy collection will improve execution time of your code a lot.

Comment: Mind you, he should probably `force` the view once he has finished chaining the operations, since these operations will be recomputed for the elements each time they are used. You should explain when using views are slower, and what does it mean to force them.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are not type-erased, Vectors are. Basically, JVM gives `Array` an advantage over other collections when handling primitives that cannot be overcome. Scala's `specialization` might decrease that advantage, but, given their cost in code size, they can't be used everywhere.